# NetBeans IDEでコマンドライン引数を指定する方法

Tags: c++

NetBeansのC ++プロジェクトでコマンドライン引数を指定する方法を教えてください。

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

`argc`と`**argv`に値（ファイル）を与えたいです。

Comment: 使ってないのでよくわかりませんが、プロジェクトノードのプロパティの実行から設定できませんか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetBeans IDE 8.0.2の場合、コマンドライン引数はProjectのPropertiesのRun Commandで指定出来ました。以下はコマンドライン引数に"arg1"、"arg2"、"arg3"、"arg4"という文字列を指定した例です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]